# SpringData Cassandara findAll method returns only one record

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Creating a project with SpringData using Reactive Cassandra repository. I have sample Book application where I wrote custom query.

```
    @GetMapping("/books2")
    public Flux<Book2> getBooks(@Valid @RequestBody Book2 book ){

        MapId id1 = id( "id", book.getId()).with("isbn", book.getIsbn());
        if(Objects.nonNull(book.getName()))
            id1.with( "name", book.getName());
        if(Objects.nonNull(book.getLocalDate()))
            id1.with( "localDate", book.getLocalDate());


        return book2Repository.findAllById( Collections.singletonList(id1));
    }
```

I have many rows but return result is only one.

Looking into code SimpleReactiveCassandraRepository.java,

```
    public Flux<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids) {
        Assert.notNull(ids, "The given Iterable of ids must not be null");
        if (FindByIdQuery.hasCompositeKeys(ids)) {
            return this.findAllById((Publisher)Flux.fromIterable(ids));
        } else {
            FindByIdQuery query = FindByIdQuery.forIds(ids);
            List<Object> idCollection = query.getIdCollection();
....
....
    public Flux<T> findAllById(Publisher<ID> idStream) {
        Assert.notNull(idStream, "The given Publisher of ids must not be null");
        return Flux.from(idStream).flatMap(this::findById);
    }
```

The findAllById seem to check if Query has composite key and calls "findAllById"  which seem to call findById , which return single record.

How do i get to return multiple rows ?

Is this a bug ?

I tried with 2.2.7 and 3.0.1 spring-data-cassandara and results seems same.